# How to plot specific value counts?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
Col 1   Col 2       Col 3
  0      No         2901
         Yes         639
  1      No         1858
         Yes         415
  2      No         1366
         Yes         252
  3      No         1236
         Yes         277
```

Say I have the following list. Essentially I'd like to create a double line graph with Col 1 on x and the counts for Yes/No (Col 3) on y. I'm having trouble doing this with the list. Would it be easier to just create 2 separate dataframes of Yes and No and then plot?

Answer (score 0):

Use [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to make `Col 2` values column names, and then simply use plot:

```
df.pivot(index="Col 1", columns="Col 2", values="Col 3").plot()
```

Pivot is needed, since pandas draws separate line per column.

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation to OP so he understand the solution better? Thanks.